# SSRS Expression error with IIF

Tags: reporting-services, iif

i have on my report a field with inside this expression:

```
=First(Fields!namefield.Value, "namedataset")
```

namefield is a boolean data type and always return true or false

but when i want to change expression in

```
=Iif(First(Fields!namefield.Value, "namedataset"), "True option", "False option")
```

return #Error.

Why?

Edit for more details
I tried follow expression

```
=Iif(1000>100, "True option", "False option")
```

and it works fine then problem is First(Fields!namefield.Value, "namedataset")

Comment: Cannot reproduce you problem with VS2005. Are you actually using the expression you posted? Or the error could be raised by IIf TruePart/FalsePart?

Comment: Also works in VS2008. Are you *sure* `nameField` is being seen as a boolean? Does `=CBool(First(Fields!namefield.Value, "namedataset"))` work? `=Iif(CBool(First(Fields!namefield.Value, "namedataset")), "True option", "False option")`?

Comment: thanks for your reply, im using VS2010, namefield comes from Dataset by a boolean field im sure, btw every try to convert with cbool gives an error

Comment: Verify field type in your report. If you don't find Report Data window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404297/why-cant-i-see-the-report-data-window-when-creating-reports

Comment: hello, how can verify field type with that window? there is not property window

Comment: ok found it is a boolean data type

Comment: So it's another problem. Is "nameddataset" defined in the object that you are using (i.e. Tablix)? What happened if you simply use First(Fields!namefield.Value)?

Comment: if i simply use First(Fields!namefield.Value) will return true or false

Comment: Are you using a Tablix? It seems that "nameddataset" is not defined in the object you are using (or at a report level). Very strange that the first expression you posted works: are you simply modified the expression to use IIf or create another field in a different position of report?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39809/discussion-between-massimo-and-tezzo)